# Еще о часах: "не ровен час"

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация

И еще о часах. Есть выражение "не ровен час" в значении "как бы не". Тоже хотелось бы узнать происхождение этого выражения, а еще — отделяется ли оно запятой, например: "Не ровен час(,) упадет".

Comment: Можно подлить масла в огонь? В этом выражении есть еще трудности с НЕ (слитно или раздельное) и с ударением (о или ё).   http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1905

Answer (score 4):

Час - это время. Не ровен час - значит, мы не знаем, чем может обернуться время. Может случиться что угодно, к худшему надо быть готовым.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, это выражение - обережное, так же, как, например, "Чур меня!" Связано оно с представлением о том, что время по своей природе - неоднородно: есть благоприятные часы, а есть такие, в которые нельзя не только делать что-либо, но даже и говорить о каких-то возможных неприятностях, чтобы их не "накликать", не сделать случайно высказанное предположение реальностью. Но вот только какой именно час окажется роковым - люди не знали. (По некоторым, очень смутным представлениям, это могли быть, например, моменты восхода и заката Солнца, а также полночь - самое "глухое" и тёмное время суток, но это не достоверно. Могло также быть время от полуночи и до рассвета.) Поэтому и говорят: "Не ровен час" - в смысле "Пусть этот час не окажется "дурным", несущим беду".

Answer (score 1):

**1) Происхождение фрзеологизма**

Течет время жизни,  и это  время, измеренное в часах, бывает разное — благоприятное или несущее в себе потенциальную опасность. Мы надеемся на спокойное существование, но не ровён час...

**2) Обособление**

Розенталь относит это выражение к вводным словам (выражение чувства), то есть требуется обособление [XXVI. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ СЛОВАХ, ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИ НЕ СВЯЗАННЫХ С ЧЛЕНАМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm)
В то же время варианты без обособления  тоже часто встречаются, в этом случае выражение, очевидно, приравнивается к частице.

**Не ровен час** увидят, сразу на кол или на плаху. [Николай Дежнев. Принцип неопределенности (2009)] ― Пойдем, родненький… А то **не ровен час** застудишься… [Михаил Елизаров. Библиотекарь (2007)]

**Не ровен час,** и сюда могут наведаться. [Евгений Сухов. Делу конец -- сроку начало (2007)] Сбежит, **не ровен час**, и деньги пропадут… [Евгений Ясин. , 2003.07.24]