# "Не" в "Не ровён час"

Tags: частица-не

Не ровён час.

Почему краткое прилагательное пишется с "не" раздельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь подразумевается **противопоставление**: не ровен час, а очень разный. Надо понимать содержание этого определения: время то благоприятное, а то вдруг сулит опасность.

О значении выражения:

[Еще о часах: "не ровен час"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18326/%D0%95%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81)